# Can't install a library to open audio files in Anaconda

Tags: python, audio, tensorflow, anaconda

I've been working on fixing this problem since really early Monday (yesterday) morning.

I'm using Anaconda and trying to use tensorflow to create neural networks and I've reached the stage where I'm supposed to create the functions that feed audio into a neural network. The problem is that to do that properly, I need a library that I can use to convert MP3 files to WAVE files automatically, but I can't seem to get hold of said library. Pydub installs, but can't be imported, ffmpeg won't even install and tinytag installs, but seems to not have a save or export function. I tried installing or using each of these libraries in Anaconda Python 3.6 and Anaconda Python 3.3. I also tried to install other audio libraries and failed.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydub'

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ffmpeg (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ffmpeg
```

I'm on Windows 10 Home. How do I solve this problem? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydub and load the wheel for your python version.

Go to downloads and try: pip install wheel_name or conda install wheel

It can be that you have to insert some data in your sitepackage folder manually using full anaconda installation